# Gulp. Сборка проекта происходит, но папка build пустая

Tags: javascript, html, вёрстка, gulp, frontend

Здравствуйте! Пилю новый проект, сборщик - Gulp. Столкнулся с какой-то непонятной и до этого времени не встречавшейся мне проблемой - сборка проекта происходит (судя по терминалу в Webstorm), но конечная папка с построенным проектом остается пустой. Для того чтобы инклюдить html-файлы используется плагин `rigger`. Ниже привожу код `gulpfile`, в нём пока только таска для сборки html.

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch'),
    prefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    rigger = require('gulp-rigger'),
    cssmin = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant'),
    rimraf = require('rimraf'),
    browserSync = require("browser-sync"),
    reload = browserSync.reload;


var path = {
    build: {
        html: 'build/'
    },
    src: {
        html: 'src/*.html'

    },
    watch: {
        html: 'src/**/*.html'
    },
    clean: './build'
};

gulp.task('html:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.html) //Выберем файлы по нужному пути
        .pipe(rigger()) //Прогоним через rigger
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.html)) //Выплюнем их в папку build
        .pipe(reload({stream: true})); //И перезагрузим наш сервер для обновлений
});
```

Пути прописаны верно. Скрин структуры проекта [прилагаю](http://prntscr.com/fb191a).
Сборка происходит корректно - [скрин](http://prntscr.com/fb191a).

Что не так то?

Comment: @LieutenantJimDangle, ничего не изменилось

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в названии папки-корня проекта. После удаления квадратных скобок все заработало.